# CMake project including more file?

Tags: visual-studio, opencv, cmake

Basically I have a folder `/myOpenCVProject/`

Where I have:

```
header.hpp
main.cpp
helper.cpp
```

And the CMakeLists.txt

```
SET( PROJECT_NAME myOpenCVProject )
PROJECT( ${PROJECT_NAME} )
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)
FIND_PACKAGE( OpenCV REQUIRED )
ADD_EXECUTABLE( ${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp )
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( ${PROJECT_NAME} ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

How can I tell to CMake to include `header` and `helper` files too ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to include them in the `ADD_EXECUTABLE` command:

```
ADD_EXECUTABLE( ${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp helper.cpp header.hpp)
```

For full details on `ADD_EXECUTABLE`, run

```
cmake --help-command add_executable
```